# Personal style-only edits?

Tags: discussion

I saw this edit in the review queue today. Both question and edit are from newbies. In my opinion, the style edits it contains don't do much for clarity and are more about personal taste (especially the final two exclamation points which are clearly out of bounds IMO). While something like, say, properly formatting a big code block would be appropriate, I don't find this edit to be worthy and intend to reject it. But I thought I'd put it to the floor: agree that this edit is more personal taste than general clarity and should be rejected?

[image: The edit in question]

Comment: I usually reject such edits as "too minor".

Answer (score 4):

I've approved this edit because in my opinion the new formatting looks better and is better for reading. Sure, there is no great change has been made. But I think it's still good for a beginner to gain experience in editing. One thing we probably need to do - notice the "newbie" user that he needs to bring more meaning into the editing in the future.

Comment: Exclamation marks aside, I agree that the edit helped call out important terms and improved readability. Is there a way to comment on edits to help the user improve?